# Background-size CSS property not working correctly in IOS devices on safari

Tags: html, css, ios

I have a body background size set. It works well as intended in android and windows. The size of background is okay there. But when loading my site on iphone the background size specifically the height looks too big to be 5%. background-size: 85% 5%; So the width is 85% of the body and height is 5% of the body but the height looks 50% of the viewport which is weird. Why this is happening only on iphone. Adding webkit prefix won't work I think. Is there anything wrong with ios and safari ...? Am I missing anything ...? Help me to fix this if you know what's going on. Thanks in advance ...

CSS

```
body 
{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, white, white, #98AEC4, white, #98AEC4, white, white) fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center; 
    background-size: 85% 5%; 
}
```

How browsers calculate the body background height ..? Other browsers are taking viewport height but in iphone the parameters are not matching up ...

Answer (score 1):

The way you used `fixed` is a shortcut for `background-attachment: fixed;`.

This property isn't well supported. Check [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/background-attachment) to know what's the current support.

A fixed-position element with a height set to 100% behaves just like the element with `background: .... fixed;` property.

So, instead of having a property on `body` you should create a `div` this way (see the one with `background` class):

```html
<head>
<style>
  .background {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, white, white, #98AEC4, white, #98AEC4, white, white);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center; 
    background-size: 85% 5%; 
  }
  .long-div {
    height: 100vh;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="long-div">Scroll down to see it how it behaves on scroll </div>
  <div class="long-div">Here you are at half of the scroll </div>
  <div>Here you are at bottom of the scroll.</div>
</body>
```

You can find a well documented article on CSS-TRICKS [The Fixed Background Attachment Hack](https://css-tricks.com/the-fixed-background-attachment-hack/).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer which is a nice trick. But I kinda fixed it for iphone by detecting ios devices and changing some of the styles.

Answer (score -1):

For iPhones safari, I think you have to add background-attachment in the media query

```
@media (max-width : @iphone-screen){
background-attachment: scroll;
```

}

Comment: what is @iphone-screen ... can you describe how to use the predefined variable ...?

Comment: Just add iPhone's screen size in place of @iphone-screen